# trouble requiring a package I published to npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, require

I am having trouble requiring a package I published to npm

after doing

```
npm install binaryconversor
```

I have tried different ways of implementing it.

```
let conversor = require('binaryconversor');
let conversor = require('./binaryconversor');
```

not sure correct way

package.json of the package I published.

```
{
  "name": "binaryconversor",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "description": "Converts binary to decimal and decimal to binary",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\"&& exit 1"
  },
  "author": "florovarelaa",
  "license": "ISC",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/florovarelaa/binaryConversor.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/florovarelaa/binaryConversor/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/florovarelaa/binaryConversor#readme"
}
```

binaryconversor.js exports module

```
module.exports = {
    b2d: binaryToDecimal,
    d2b: decimalToBinary
}
```

tests.js file in another directory

```
let conversor = require('binaryconversor');
```

Then I run 
`node tests`
Error shown:

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
    throw err;
    ^

```
Error: Cannot find module 'binaryconversor'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Floro\Documents\Programacion\javascript\Node\tests\tests.js:1:79)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
```

Comment: Did you install the package with `npm install`?

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with not having index.js, It may not be the best way to fix the error, but changing the file containing module.exports to index.js solved the issue.